# Travelled time between two geographical points isn't returning the correct time

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I'm using osmnx to get the travelled distance between multiple points. The problem is that I don't think that it is returning the correct distance. The sample code can be checked above:

```
origin=ox.nearest_nodes(self.G, o_longitude, o_latitude)
destin=ox.nearest_nodes(self.G, d_longitude, d_latitude)
                                    
time=nx.shortest_path_length(self.G, origin, destin, weight='travel_time')
inversed_time=nx.shortest_path_length(self.G, destin, origin, weight='travel_time')
```

As an example of what I think is the code failing, take:

```
o_longitude=-8.51691 
o_latitude=41.244881
d_longitude=-8.612829 
d_latitude=41.172129
```

For this points, the time returned is 297.6 s. But if I use google maps to check, the travelled time between this two points is at minimum 12 minutes (=720 s).
I thought that the error could be related to the approximation to the nearest node, so i checked what were the coordinates of the origin and destin points (e.g., the nearest nodes).

```
origin=(41.179425, -8.57307)
destin=(41.171829, -8.612744)
```

But even afterwards, when checking the travelled time with google maps it is, at minimum, 7 minutes (420 s).

I don't know why this is happening and I don't have any idea on how to fix it.
The graph I'm using is a graph I downloaded from open street map of Porto's District. The query to get the graph is the following:

```
G = ox.graph_from_place("Distrito do Porto", network_type="drive", simplify=False)
```

And after I add edge lengths, travel time and speed with this:

```
G=ox.distance.add_edge_lengths(G)
G=ox.speed.add_edge_speeds(G)
G=ox.speed.add_edge_travel_times(G, precision=1)
```

Thanks anyways.

If anyone could help, I would be thankful.

Comment: 1) `The graph I'm using is a graph I downloaded from open street map of Porto's District.` Can you include the query you used? 2) How did you add speeds to each edge of the map? Did you use [add_edge_speeds](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.speed), or something similar?

Comment: @NickODell Hi, I added all that information now. Thanks

Comment: Google maps and osmnx are answering slightly different questions. osmnx is calculating how fast you could go if you went the speed limit everywhere. Google maps is doing that plus accounting for traffic.